# Manipulate the first value of a recursive function, redraw plot

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, recursion, interactive

*I'm new to this, casually executing basic lines of code online in Wolfram Lab; and I have a question I couldn't figure myself.*

---

Example; I have a recursive function and its initial value

```
f[x_]:=Log[Abs[f[x-1]]]
f[0] = 2
```

I can draw the connecting plot for the initial value:

```
ListPlot[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100}], Joined -> True]
```

I would like to know how can I manipulate `f[0]=k` and redraw the plot as I move the slider:

```
Manipulate[f[0]=k, {k, 0, 10, 1}]
```

---

Can you then nest multiple plots of this same kind on the same graph in colors, each having their own $k_1,k_2,k_3\dots$ sliders?

Comment: `Manipulate[f[x_] := Log[Abs[f[x - 1]]];
 f[0] = k; ListPlot[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100}], Joined -> True], {k , 0, 2}]`?

Comment: @kglr That seems to work for a moment but ends up collapsing; Instead of a graph I see a red rectangle in the white area under the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RecurrenceTable` with vector initial values `{k1, k2, k3, k4}`:

```
ClearAll[f]

Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Transpose@RecurrenceTable[{f[x] == Log[Abs[f[x - 1]]], 
  f[0] == {k1, k2, k3, k4}}, f, {x, 1, 40}], PlotRange -> {-5, 5}], 
 {{k1, 2}, 2, 10}, {{k2, 2}, 2, 10}, {{k3, 2}, 2, 10}, {{k4, 2}, 2, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Thought it collapsing must have something to do with Wolfram Lab itself I think. It randomly switches me from "Use as a deployable object
instead" and "Use as a manipulate expression
instead", and sometime just collapses either way.

Comment: Vepir, thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to recommend a somewhat different approach, just in my own style. I hope it is helpful, despite kglr already offering a suitable work up.

```
f[k0_][x_]:=f[k0][x]=Log[Abs[f[k0][x-1]]]
f[k0_][0]:=f[k0][0]=k0
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  Transpose[Table[{f[k1][x],f[k2][x],f[k3][x],f[k4][x]},{x,0,10,1}]],
  Joined->True
 ],
 {{k1,2},2,10},{{k2,3},2,10},{{k3,4},2,10},{{k4,5},2,10}
]
```

This makes use of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and also gives us a chance to make use of the function in other ways if we want, e.g.

```
f[k0][7]
(* Output= Log[Abs[Log[Abs[Log[Abs[Log[Abs[Log[Abs[Log[Abs[Log[Abs[k0]]]]]]]]]]]]]] *)
N[f[3]/@Range[6]]
(* Output= {1.09861,0.0940478,-2.36395,0.860335,-0.150434,-1.89423} *)
```

Screen capture:

[image: Image of Wolfram Programming Lab Session Using Code Above]

Comment: I appreciate this :)